# python - If statement inside For loop with condition to execute else, only if all iterations are over

Tags: python

I am a newbie in python and I know there is something very wrong with the following code.

```
name = 'spider-man'
movies = []
movieframe = ['Spider-Man 3\xa0', 'The Amazing Spider-Man\xa0', 'Spider-Man 2\xa0', 'The Amazing Spider-Man 2\xa0', 'Spider-Man\xa0', 'Spider-Man: Homecoming\xa0']
for i in movieframe:
    if name.lower() == i.lower():
        movies.append(name)
        print('a', movies)

    else:
        movies.append(movieframe[0])
        print('b', movies)
        break
```

I want to check if the exact string present in the dataframe, if true, append it to another dataframe. But in the above for loop, 'else' is being executed after first iteration itself.

How do I correct it?

Comment: There is no `spider-man` in list so `else` will exec every time , what did you expect?

Comment: It's there in 'movieframe[4]' in lower case, but it is not going beyond 'movieframe[0]'.

Comment: remove the `break`, then continue debugging

Comment: Try dedenting the else block. I think that should get you closer to what you want (even if it's not entirely clear what exactly that might be). The `break` should probably go with the `if`, not  the `else` clause

Comment: I did, all I got was 'else statement' appended 5 times.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, same result!

Comment: This is probably because `'spider-man'.lower() !=  'Spider-Man\xa0'.lower()`, you do not have anything in your list that will be equal to `'spider-man'.lower()` when converted to lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are using **List** and **Dataframe** is totally a different thing.

Now, why are you using **\xa0**?

**\xa0** is actually non-breaking space in Latin1, instead, use u' ' or remove them from movieframe.

Or simply you can use `name='spiderman\xa0'`.

You are getting the wrong answer because **\xa0** is an additional character that is not present in `name`.

```
name = 'spider-man\xa0'
movies = [] 
movieframe = ['Spider-Man 3\xa0', 'The Amazing Spider-Man\xa0', 'Spider-Man 
2\xa0', 'The Amazing Spider-Man 2\xa0', 'Spider-Man\xa0', 'Spider-Man: 
Homecoming\xa0']
for i in movieframe:
    if name.lower() == i.lower():
       movies.append(name)
       print('a', movies)
if len(movies)==0:
   movies.append(movieframe[0])
   print('b', movies)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append to another dataframe, first initialize it and then append the contents within the loop

Example :

```
movies = pd.DataFrame() ##### This will create a empty dataframe which can be appended into within the for loop.
```

Or if your intention is just to create an output dataframe, then create and append into a list as you have done in your code. Then once out of the for loop, create a dataframe with the list you have created within the loop

From your code, it should be something like:

```
movieDF = pd.DataFrame(movies) ##### movies is a list type
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expressions:

```
name = 'spider-man'
movies = []
movieframe = ['Spider-Man 3\xa0', 'The Amazing Spider-Man\xa0', 'Spider-Man 2\xa0', 'The Amazing Spider-Man 2\xa0', 'Spider-Man\xa0', 'Spider-Man: Homecoming\xa0']
import re
movieframe = [x.lower() for x in movieframe]
for x in movieframe:
    if re.search("spider-man",x):
        movies.append(x)
print(movies)
```

['spider-man 3\xa0', 'the amazing spider-man\xa0', 'spider-man 2\xa0', 'the amazing spider-man 2\xa0', 'spider-man\xa0', 'spider-man: homecoming\xa0']